# How to find text field is readonly or not in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i find a box attr is readonly or not from jquery, Then only i can focus next text box.

```
<input type="text" name="mrp1" id="mrp1" value="" readonly>
```

Please give me a solution for this.

Comment: `if ( $('input').is('[readonly]') ) { }`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do `$(input:not([readonly]))` and then `.focus()` on the first result?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please post your Javascript snippet so we can see what you have tried. That way people do not duplicate your effort. Also, try a web search for this, as I expect you'll find many solutions already available. If you have problems with them, edit you question with an example and somebody may be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript,

```
if(document.querySelector("#myText").readOnly) { // logic goes here }
```

In Jquery,

```
if ( $('#mrp1').is('[readonly]') ) { // logic goes here }
```

Comment: Thanks bro, JavaScript works for me, i think , i am writing like readonly (instant readonly='true') so jquery not working. and document.querySelector("#mrp"+ival+"[readonly]") is also working for me

Comment: I've got something weird going on.  I see the tabindex being correctly set in the HTML, but for some reason it's jumping to the last textbox (the readonly one) on the line.  I forgot to originally mention that I'm using TextBoxFor, so not sure if that's what's causing the problem.

Comment: In the javascript example, remove the # tag!